# Input element position absolute and width auto does not work in IE

Tags: css

I need to get auto width of input element, relative to it's parrent.

HTML

```
<div id="overlay">
    <input type="text" id="inner_input" value="aaa" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
#overlay {
    position: relative;
    background: #ccc;
    height: 50px;
}
#inner_input {
    position: absolute;
    height: auto;
    width: auto;
    display: block;
    top: 10px;
    bottom: 10px;
    left: 10px;
    right: 40px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #ededed;
}
```

But this is does not work in IE. What is the problem?

**Here is** [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yQWGV/151/)

**UPDATE**

What is interesting, if I use a div instead of input, it works! It means that in iE there is browser defined rule for input element, which do not allow to work properly...

Comment: Not related, but always make sure you list the unprefixed properties *after* prefixed properties (re: box-sizing).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `%` instead of `auto` something like  `width: 90%;` and will work

Comment: Yes, but I do not need percents. I need fixed offsets.